# UUID and MAC Address in MS Azure

Tags: azure, virtualization

I need two unique identifiers for a particular VM instance.
Can I assume that MAC address and UUID (from dmidecode command) are constant and remain same through the lifetime of VM instance (i.e does not change at reboots,start,stop of instances) ?

Regards
Geetika

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this / do they now do static addressing?

Answer (score 0):

No. I have just rebooted azure VM, it changed the MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround. You can execute a script when a new Network Adapter is added to a VM through AzurePack. The script will set the MAC Address to a Static entry. The MAC address will be picked from the pool of available ones.

See [this](http://www.isolation.se/azure-pack-sma-script-to-set-a-static-mac-address-for-new-virtual-nics/) blog entry for more details.

Comment: Doesn't apply to Azure hosted VMs - only applys to Windows running AzurePack (according to the author of the blog - see comments).